# Maven version range picking up unexpected dependency

Tags: java, maven

I'm having a dependency defined with a [version range](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html):

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>[8.0.33,9.0.0)</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Reading up on maven versions, I expected it to be of the "[1.0,2.0) -> 1.0 <= x < 2.0" variety. But a `dependency:tree` results in the following resolved version:

> +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.0.M9:provided

How can I tell Maven to use any [Major](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855) 8 version starting at incremental version 33? I'm currently working around it by using `[8.0.33,8.5.4]` instead.

Comment: Any reason why you're using version ranges for build? Why not just put `8.0.33` directly. Since otherwise you're violating the principle of reproducible builds

Comment: A milestone in Maven is before the final release and that's the reason why this version `9.0.0.M9` is included which is correct. And of course best is to prevent using version ranges at all...Furthermore if you set scope provided it does not really matter which version someone else will use...

Comment: @vikingsteve It is a commons project that allows depending projects to pin down a specific version without collisions.

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you provide a source? According to the [official documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html) there's no such thing as milestones, only incremental-versions and it is unclear how Maven deals with that. /edit, found it: http://www.mojohaus.org/development/process.html#Versioning_and_Release_Strategy (although they don't call it milestones).

Comment: First to be clear mojohaus is not Apache Maven. So what you have cited as `Offical Documentation` is *not* the offical documentation unfortunately it currently does not exist such documentation which means [it should be created](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-291).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the how version comparsion results in Maven via the folloing command line:

```
java -jar apache-maven-3.3.9/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar 9.0.0 9.0.0.M9
```

which results in the following:

```
Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 9.0.0 == 9
   9.0.0 > 9.0.0.M9
2. 9.0.0.M9 == 9.0.0.milestone-9
```

which shows that `9.0.0` is greater than `9.0.0.M9` ...which means the result you got was correct.

Comment: Ahh, nice. Thanks. Do you know of any documentation as to why it is so? All I can really find in the official documentation is that that would be the "incremental version". How Maven deals with the incremental version is unclear to me as well. Edit: found it: http://www.mojohaus.org/development/process.html#Versioning_and_Release_Strategy

Comment: Still, is there a way to exclude newer major numbers (including it's beta micro versions)?

Comment: If you really like you can do `[8.0.33,8.999.999]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maven absolute comparisons between version numbers when resolving a version range. ie. It compares the version exactly as they are, not what you meant.

That means that version `9.0.0.M9` is considered less than `9.0.0` and so is part of the range `[8.0.33,9.0.0)`.

I have created issue [MNG-5353](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5353) to exclude pre-release version numbers when comparing exclusive upper bounds, but this has not been implemented yet.

Excluding pre-release versions when comparing an exclusive upper bound would allow you to specify semantic version ranges in the form you used: `[8.0.33,9.0.0)`.

In the mean time, you can use something like: `[8.0.33,8.999.999]` to define a semantic version range.