# Maven Version Range To Exclude Next Minor Version

Tags: maven

I am using Maven 3.3.3 and want to express that I will accept any 2.7.x version of the `jackson-core` dependency (but am not willing to go to 2.8.x until I've had a chance to assess for backward compatibility, run unit / regression tests, etc.).

This would allow my project to receive bug fixes (under incremental versions), but delay the jump to the next `minor` version until ready.

I instinctively wrote the following into `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>[2.7.1,2.8)</version>
```

However, a `mvn dependency:list` says that the following version is used:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.0.rc2:compile
```

I was taken aback by that, however dug up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482463/228838) which leads to the "official" [Maven Javadoc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html) which describes the sort order of Maven dependencies.

Those helped me understand why `2.8.0.rc2` is considered "older" than `2.8.0`.

So, I reasoned that the following would (albeit hack-ishly) produce the desired results:
    [2.7.1,2.8.0.a)

I was wrong.  The `dependency:list` now produces:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.0:compile
```

Same result with (or variations with `-a`):
    [2.7.1,2.8.a)

All together, this seems to imply the following orderings:

```
2.8.0 < 2.8.0.a 
2.8.0.rc2 < 2.8.0
```

So ... if everything I learned in school about transitive relationships is correct, then:

```
2.8.0.rc2 < 2.8.0.a
```

That seems to contradict the SO answer.  At the same time, the Javadoc is ambiguous (i.e. is the qualifier ordering listed the *actually* implemented ordering) and [this Apache Wiki / Confluence page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Versioning) is mildly confusing.

Regardless, it doesn't seem to line up with either String sorting or common sense that a "Release Candidate" (assumed meaning for `rc` would precede an alpha version specified as `a`).

Would this be handled differently if there an actual `2.8.0-alpha` version had been released?

Bottom line:  is there a reasonably transferable way to specify a Maven Version Range which excludes everything in the 2.8.0 version space?

**Edit:** Even more bottom line... is there a clearly documented and publicly available description of the Maven version ordering algorithm *outside* of their source code?  It's hard to tell if the cwiki page is a desired spec or implemented (and certainly doesn't go to the level of detail we're exploring here) and the Javadoc seems to imply (but isn't unambiguous in stating so) the equality between `.` and `-` which comments here demonstrate is not the case.

Comment: `[2.7.1,2.8.0-alpha-alpha)` does the trick... a bit of a hack.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't do the trick.  `java -jar ${maven-home}/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.3.jar 2.8.0-alpha.alpha 2.8.0-alpha-alpha` (see @khmarbaise answer) says (in part): `2.8.0-alpha.alpha < 2.8.0-alpha-alpha` ... so there *is* something less than `alpha-alpha` (note the `.` separator).  This feels like whack-a-mole.

Comment: It gets more interesting... `2.8.0-alpha.alpha > 2.8.0-alpha.alpha[.-]alpha` since there does not seem to be a limit on the number of post-fixed qualifiers that are considered as part of a version number by Maven.

Comment: This is looking more and more like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888812/maven-version-range-picking-up-unexpected-dependency.  Certainly a h/t to @khmarbaise for references and resources there.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the ordering by using the following command:

```
java -jar apache-maven-3.3.3/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.3.jar 2.8.0.rc2 2.8.0.a

Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 2.8.0.rc2 == 2.8.0.rc-2
   2.8.0.rc2 < 2.8.0.a
2. 2.8.0.a == 2.8.0.a
```

You can also check the other version `2.8.0-alpha` via:

```
java -jar apache-maven-3.3.3/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.3.jar 2.8.0.rc2 2.8.0-alpha
Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 2.8.0.rc2 == 2.8.0.rc-2
   2.8.0.rc2 > 2.8.0-alpha
2. 2.8.0-alpha == 2.8-alpha
```

Comment: Thanks for this tool tip.  It was clearly helpful in running some test cases (see elsewhere).  However, still looking for a canonical answer re/ how Maven orders the versions numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Maven itself says [there is no official documentation until this bug is resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-291).

Further, given what is stated in comments on the original question, I am concluding that there is no 100% safe, transferable of stating version numbers in a range for a more permanent solution.

*Practically*, I suppose making assumptions would render either of these valid for most uses:

```
[2.7.0,2.8.-alpha.alpha)
[2.7.0,2.7.9999.9999]
```

But *theoretically*, there could always be a smaller (in the first case) or larger (in the second) version number of the artifact (note that `2.7.9999.9999.9 > 2.7.9999.9999`).

Even with those assumptions, stating the range in either manner leaves a build accepting any `2.7.x` version published which might (for example) be `2.7.1-rc2`.

I know realize this was an implied premise in my original question.  That is, asking to "receive bug fixes (under incremental versions), but delay the jump to the next minor version until ready" assumed that the "incremental versions" are only non-alpha, non-rc, etc. versions.

That premise is invalid.  Providing "only unqualified versions (eg. `maj.min.inc` with no `-qualifer`)" does not seem to be a use case supported by Maven and is a separate question entirely.

I think I'm now firmly in the "Maven Ranges are Evil" camp... not as much for build reproducibility reasons as much as being able to control the quality / finality of the included artifacts.